# how to get a result from tensorflow.estimator for dataframe having a single input only

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

> code for inputting the values from user and getting a prediction from model

```
 m=[]
for j in range(0,1):
    l=[]
    print("enter new person details")
    for i in range(0,7):
        print("please enter the values")
        a=float(input())
        l.append(a)
input_vector_df=pd.DataFrame(m,columns=feat_cols)
prediction_input_function=tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=input_vector_df,shuffle=False)#
prediction1=model.predict(prediction_input_function)
my_predb=list(prediction1)
print(mypredb[0])
```

error after running these lines of codes

```
   self._epoch_end = (self._trav - 1) % self._max
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

model training code:

```
input_func=tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)
model=tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols,n_classes=2)
model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=1000)
eval_input_func=tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test,y=y_test,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1,shuffle=False)
results=model.evaluate(eval_input_func)
print(results)
```

function for normalizing the data

```
diabetes[cols_to_norm]=diabetes[cols_to_norm].apply(lambda x:(x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input_vector_df` is made from an empty list `m`. A `ZeroDivisionError` is being raised by `model.predict()` which is trying predict the output for an empty input.

Comment: when i am correcting the above mistake  i am getting ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 7), indices imply (8, 7).